# Change date range in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set start and end date in date picker where start date is week before current date and end date is week after start date. In certain condition it gives me 0 for start date. Can anyone look into code below and help me to get proper date range when current date is first day of the month or last date of the month. Thanks for your help.

```
 var date = new Date();
```

//When current date was less then 7 in some situation it giving me error. So, I am checking current date and randomly subtract 3. 
    //if current date is less then 7 then get the last day of the previous month
    if (date.getDate() <= 7) {

```
    day = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0);        
    startdate = day.getDate() - 3;
    month = day.getMonth() + 1;
    year = day.getFullYear();

    if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
    if (day < 10) day = day;
    console.log("App Config: lasy day: " + startdate + "\nmonth: " + month + "\nyear:" + year);
}

else {

    startdate = date.getDate() - 7;
    month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    year = date.getFullYear();

    if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
    if (day < 10) day = day;

    console.log("App Config: day: " + startdate + "\nmonth: " + month + "\nyear:" + year);
}

return month + "/" + startdate + "/" + year;
```

Comment: Which datepicker you using?

Comment: You don't need to deal with wrapping the month yourself. If you use `date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7)` it will figure it out automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
var dt = new Date();
var weekBefore = dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 7);
var weekAfter = dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 7);
```

JavaScript will figure it out automatically the date 7 days before and after!

Comment: Above code will still work if current date is less then 7. For example, if current date is 02/05/2015 then according to your code will it give 01/28/2015.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with plugins I would suggest [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which is great for date handling. Adding a week would be as easy as

```
var inOneWeek = moment().add(1, 'weeks');//.format('DD/MM/YYYY'); if u want it in DD/MM/YYYY format
var oneWeekAgo = moment().add(-1, 'weeks');//.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

otherwise @sabotero's answer would do as well.